# Ruby: Appending, reading remote files

Tags: ruby, ssh

I need to append lines to a file on a remote server via SSH in Ruby. At the moment I'm doing it with the decidedly inelegant:

```
Net::SSH.start(host, user) do |ssh|
  ssh.exec!("echo #{string} >> #{path}")
end
```

I'm guessing (hoping?) this isn't the best way to go about such things. Any suggestions?

Comment: Only other way I can imagine is to change file locally and reupload which makes no sense really. Are there any problems with this solution? (except that file may get cluttered)

Comment: I guess not - I'm nervous about running a system command with those #{string} & #{path} params passed in. I'll sanitise those two params, but it's a little more powerful than I was hoping for a simple appending to file. Thanks anyhow

Comment: Yeah, this more of a concern over typos than security, what about limiting the path and sanitizing input (so that `../../something` is not possible).